# How to keep texts centered and aligned between 2 separate columns using Bootstrap

Tags: css, vertical-alignment, text-justify

I currently have a responsive page that in desktop mode contains 2 columns with text that is centered and aligned. So far, so good. But when I reduce the resolution and switch to mobile mode, I want to get a single column with text that remains centered and aligned, but that's not the case.

Here's what I get in mobile mode :

```
+------------------------+
|      text              |
|      short text        |
|      long text         |
|   another text         |
|   another short text   |
|   another long text    |
+------------------------+
```

The expected behavior would be an alignment of texts between the 2 columns like this :

```
+---------------------------+
|      text                 |
|      short text           |
|      long text            |
|      another text         |
|      another short text   |
|      another long text    |
+---------------------------+
```

Here's a code snippet to help you understand better.

```html
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Bootstrap 5 Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
  <link href="test.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-lg-6 d-flex justify-content-center">
        <div>
          text<br/>
          short text<br/>
          long text<br/>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-lg-6 d-flex justify-content-center">
        <div>
          another text<br/>
          another short text<br/>
          another long text<br/>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Maybe I'm going about this the wrong way, but I've looked and I haven't found a solution. But I'm still hopeful and I hope you can help me. Thanks in advance to all for your help.

Comment: seems that you have one closing div tag in excess

Comment: @Mehdi You're right, but that doesn't solve my problem. Thanks anyway for your message.

Answer (score 0):

If I copy>paste your code with bootstrap css 3.3.7 the alignment seems to work? I assume you want the text to be aligned on the left.

```html
<head>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@3.3.7/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-lg-6 d-flex justify-content-center">
        <div>
          text<br/>
          short text<br/>
          long text<br/>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-lg-6 d-flex justify-content-center">
        <div>
          another text<br/>
          another short text<br/>
          another long text<br/>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Thank you for your fast reply, but I'd like the texts to be centered and aligned on the left between all the words.

Answer (score 0):

```html
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <title>Bootstrap 5 Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-12 d-flex justify-content-center">
        <div class="text-start">
          <div>text</div>
          <div>short text</div>
          <div>long text</div>
          <div>another text</div>
          <div>another short text</div>
          <div>another long text</div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thank you for your fast reply, but your code no longer takes into consideration the desktop part (with 2 columns), as in my example

Answer (score 0):

you need to overwrite Bootstrap Css with !important. Don't think you can achieve  it with Bootstrap alone. Why don't you try with this. You can still style it as you want

```css
.style2{
    min-width: 40%;
}

@media screen and (min-width: 992px){
    .style2{
        justify-content: center !important;
        /* align-items: center !important; */
        text-align: center !important;
    }
}
```

```html
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-lg-6 d-flex justify-content-center mystyle">
        <div class="style2">
          text<br/>
          short text<br/>
          long text<br/>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-lg-6 d-flex justify-content-center">
        <div class="style2">
          another text<br/>
          another short text<br/>
          another long text<br/>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply, but I'd like the texts to be centered and aligned on the left between all the words when is on mobile. If you look and play with my code snippet, you will see that when you get mobile reponsive, texts in the two colomun are not aligned verticaly.